# A word for 'non-animated' movies

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to denote non-animated movies?

What I have in mind is like the following:

- Disney is okay, but I prefer ??? movies.

It should mean movies where human actors/actresses play, instead of cartoons or polygons. It has nothing to do with fantasy elements and Harry Potter is a ??? movie.

I guess *real* would be understood with sufficient contexts, but is there a more specific words for "acted by humans"?

Comment: I suggest there is none, for the same reason that we once had wrist or pocket or fob watches, but now all of those are lumped together as "analogue" and portrayed as different from "digital"

I personally see the Question as disingenuous, though I see that others might accept it.

How would it not serve you to divide movies into "ordinary/traditional/standard/regular…"

Who could ever need a word - or more likely, a term - for 'non-animated' movies?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin There is a word, actually. It has been answered below, the word is "live-action".

Comment: @deadly-nightshade666 Sorry to have to point out such a primary-school problem and still "live-action" is not a word, nor any grammatical construct that could be treated as a word.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Live-action is a word. It is defined by Oxford Languages as "(in filmmaking) action involving real people or animals, as contrasted with animation or computer-generated effects."

Comment: @deadly-nightshade666 Sorry, I forgot to ask for a specific citation in which Oxford Languages says "Live-action" is a word.

Can you provide a link to a specific citation?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Yes, here's the link https://www.google.com/search?q=live-action+definition&rlz=1CADLTH_enUS1035&ei=V5qQY5yqJrPXytMP3LedgAQ&oq=live-action+&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQARgAMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMggILhCABBDUAjIFCC4QgAQyBQgAEIAEMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMggILhCABBDUAjIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEOgoIABBHENYEELADOgcIABCwAxBDOhIILhDHARDRAxDIAxCwAxBDGAE6DAguEMgDELADEEMYAToPCC4Q1AIQyAMQsAMQQxgBSgQIQRgASgQIRhgBUIkCWIkCYPQLaAFwAXgAgAFJiAFJkgEBMZgBAKABAcgBEcABAdoBBggBEAEYCA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp&safe=active&ssui=on  Another link is https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/live-action

Comment: @deadly-nightshade666 Thanks and rather than Google or Cambridge, can you prove a link to Oxford Languages, or not?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Such movies and TV are referred to as "live-action."

> **live action** *noun*
>
> (in movies, etc.) action involving real people or animals, not models,
> or images that are drawn, or produced by computer:
>
> *It’s not always easy as you might think to tell the difference between live action and an animated film.*
>
> *a live-action movie*
>
> <sub>Source: [*Cambridge Dictionary* — live
> action](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/live-action)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't it sound like 'action' movies (i.e., 'action' as a genre of the movie)?

Comment: Welcome!  This is the common term.  I encourage you to include some examples that show how it answers the question, and do take a moment to [tour].

Comment: @sundowner "Live action" is the common term and has no connotations of "action as a genre". For example, all the remakes Disney is churning out recently are officially called "live action remakes"

Comment: @sundowner, the hyphen (-) in "live-action" is significant.  It indicates that "live-action" is to be understood as a single adjective in contexts where the words might be interpreted differently without.  Especially, it emphasizes that "live-action movie" should be grouped as (live action) movie, not as live (action movie).

Comment: @NoName The distinction is starting to get a bit blurry, of course.  For example, the recent *Lion King*, which was ostensibly one of said "live action remakes", turns out to be almost 100% CG.  (I think there were some establishing B-roll shots that were actually real, but that's about it.)  So "live action" in this case refers to how it *looks*, having nothing to do with whether it was shot on camera or CG animated.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman even before CGI the line between animation and live-action has always been a bit blurry. Rotoscoping and stop-motion animation for example.

Comment: While this answer is generally correct, it'd be improved by pointing to a definition or examples of the term being used in this way.

Comment: There was some [objection](https://www.vox.com/culture/2019/7/19/20692319/lion-king-new-live-action-animated-debate-2d-3d) to the use of "live-action" as it pertained to The Lion King remake, because it was more realistic, but still largely CGI.  Reading this article helps you understand what _live-action_ is intended to mean as it pertains to animation.

Comment: @Wyck The lines have really gotten blurred these days. Nearly all big-budget live-action movies use at least some CGI, and Disney’s “animated” movies are now all CGI too, not hand-drawn. But instead of calling *Top Gun: Maverick* a revival of the moribund live-action genre, we tend to call any movie “live-action” that has realistic-looking CGI, or that uses some human actors the way *Who Framed Roger Rabbit* did.

Comment: If we must follow that route then Avery85's "live action" seems to say it all.

On the other hand, how is this different from ordinary wrist-watches being re-branded "analogue" purely by comparison with the new-fangled "digital"?

Answer (score 6):

You might just say *I prefer movies that aren't animated*, or *movies with live actors*.

The other sense of *animated* could interfere with its use to mean with cartoon characters.